# Why Does This Happen?

Tags: modeling

[image: why]

I just want both sides to lift up like the one on the left so that I can make a cool paper airplane folding animation. I tried with a plane and got the same issue. I even tried using two loop cuts in the middle and putting them right next to each other.

Update: [image]
It may be hard to see but the little dots that indicate the middle of a face are in a bunch of weird spots.

Comment: As well as @Sazerac's answer below, since paper planes are always symmetrical, you could model under a Mirror modifier. Delete the right half, then work on the left, and have the modifier do the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have overlapping faces in your model. You need to delete the ones you don't want.

If you use the dots in face select mode as a guide, it should be hard to find and delete them.

It looks like you may also have duplicated vertices, so I would suggest also using the *remove doubles* tool on your model to get rid of them.

Comment: This problem has been happening even with a blank plane though, even before I section it apart.

Answer (score 2):

in **Edit Mode**
select all, and press
<kbd>W</kbd> and **select Remove Dobles**
now pres <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
to correct normals

if you have one or more faces with inverted normals, select only the faces that have the problem, press <kbd>W</kbd> and select NORMAL FLIP

[image]
[image]